# Postfix sending to wrong email (redirection?) New setup possibly wrong configuration

Tags: centos, email, postfix, dkim

I'm having a strange issue after possibly setting up DKIM signing (might have caused this?)

Originally I was receiving emails fine (I was tricking my machine into thinking the website was on the new server via the hosts file)

```
Sep 11 12:10:01 mail postfix/pickup[4549]: 1B87110E7264: uid=48 from=<apache>
Sep 11 12:10:01 mail postfix/cleanup[4747]: 1B87110E7264: messageid=<20160911111001.1B87110E7264@mail.companyemail.co.uk>
Sep 11 12:10:01 mail postfix/qmgr[4550]: 1B87110E7264: from=<apache@mail.companyemail.co.uk>, size=884, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 11 12:10:01 mail postfix/smtp[4750]: 1B87110E7264: to=<info@companyemail.co.uk>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[108.177.15.26]:25, delay=0.36, delays=0.06/0.01/0.06/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1473592201 k65si980592wmd.53 - gsmtp)
Sep 11 12:10:01 mail postfix/qmgr[4550]: 1B87110E7264: removed
```

Which seemed to work fine.

However since setting up DKIM signing and switching the DNS A record to point the domain to the new server. I now get the following log:

```
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail postfix/pickup[5894]: 3471710EB9DE: uid=48 from=<apache>
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail postfix/cleanup[5900]: 3471710EB9DE: message-id=<20160911121023.3471710EB9DE@companyemail.co.uk>
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail opendkim[4425]: 3471710EB9DE: DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=companyemail.co.uk)
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail postfix/qmgr[5895]: 3471710EB9DE: from=<apache@companyemail.co.uk>, size=855, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail postfix/local[5903]: 3471710EB9DE: to=<root@companyemail.co.uk>, orig_to=<info@companyemail.co.uk>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep 11 13:10:23 mail postfix/qmgr[5895]: 3471710EB9DE: removed
```

Now the main difference I can see is the opendkim line and that the to= field has been changed and now there is an orig_to. I think this might be the issue as I seem to be receiving emails on the server now (as it keeps saying: You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root)

Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This log entry

```
relay=local
```

indicating that you put companyemail.co.uk in `mydestination` configuration. Check your `main.cf`.

If you want email to companyemail.co.uk go to somewhere else, remove it from that parameter.